# Getting the line number in the source code for an equation?

Tags: sourcecode, forward-inverse-search

I have a long file (about 5000 lines, the pdf is about 100 pages) and I want to find an equation with a specific number (for example: 11.5) in the source code.
Of course, I have access to all the `.aux`, `.log` files etc.

Is there a way to locate the equation in the source code? I don't want to use inverse-search from DVI, because I'll have to do this for a large number of equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have a `\label` in the source then you can look in the aux and find the label for a particular number then just search for that label in the source document.

Alternatively you could modify `\label` to output the line number as a comment in the aux (or in the log) but that has a bigger chance of breaking something.